# How to get access_token from Facebook

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to write a small application which can read the public events of a Facebook page. So I don't need a specific user access_token, this would be too much work. I wrote a small script, which should get the access_token, but it doesn't :(

```
<?php
$url= "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&    client_id=my_client_id&client_secret=my_client secret";
$access_token = file_get_contents($url);
$access_token = substr($access_token,strpos($access_token,"=")+1);
print access_token;

}
?>
```

if i open the url in my browser, I get an access_token, but this doesn't work :(

Comment: When you use `file_get_contents` the request comes from your **server**, not your clients computer, and since your **server** is not logged in to facebook, then no access token will come up.

Comment: can you share your page json or feed url so we can help you using json or feed but u can't get all the events using json method( u can last 30 around evetnts using json or feeds method....

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

[Facebook Graph API](http://benbiddington.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/facebook-graph-api-getting-access-tokens/)

Hope that helps.

Resources [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getAccessToken/)

How-To: Publishing With an App Token [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/publishing-with-app-token/)

Comment: Okay, I'm trying the facebook php sdk, here's the new code:
The facebook.php is in the same directionory
<?php

require_once("facebook.php");

$config = array();
$config[‘appId’] = '***';
$config[‘secret’] = '***';
$config[‘fileUpload’] = false; // optional

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

print $access_token;

}
?>

Answer (score 0):

Facebook needs a browser to be able to identify the user. You cannot do it using file_get_contents.

You should redirect the url and on the landing page get the access_token.

I have a small example on my blog on how to do it. See [here](http://subirkumarsao.blogspot.dk/2011/11/facebook-as-oauth.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a app_access_token this way:

```
$app_access_token = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id='.$app_id.'&client_secret='.$secret);
```

More info here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/publishing-with-app-token/